# Send SMS from SQL Server stored procedure and trigger failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have created a stored procedure for sending a sms and call it from on update trigger

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[spSendSmsSQL] 
    @Mobile varchar(20), 
    @smstext as varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @iReq int, @hr int 
    DECLARE @sUrl AS varchar(500) 
    DECLARE @errorSource VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @errorDescription VARCHAR(8000) 

    EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', @iReq OUT        

    print @hr        

    if @hr <> 0     
        RAISERROR('sp_OACreate Microsoft.XMLHTTP FAILED!', 16, 1) 

    SET @sUrl = 'http://url?numbers=#MobNo#&message=#Msg#';
    SET @sUrl = REPLACE(@sUrl,'#MobNo#',@Mobile) 
    SET @sUrl = REPLACE(@sUrl,'#Msg#',@smstext) 

    -- sms code start 
    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl, true 

    IF @hr <> 0 
        RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod Open FAILED!', 16, 1) 

    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'send' 

    SELECT @iReq

    IF @hr <> 0 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @iReq, @errorSource OUTPUT, @errorDescription OUTPUT

        SELECT 
            [Error Source] = @errorSource,
            [Description] = @errorDescription

        RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod Send FAILED!', 16, 1) 
    END 
    ELSE 
        EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @iReq 
END
```

It works fine while calling by

```
EXEC spSendSmsSQL '9999999999','SMS FROM SQLSERVER'
```

But when I'm calling it from my trigger it causes

> raise error "sp_OAMethod Open FAILED!" AND "sp_OAMethod Send FAILED!"

My trigger is :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdate] ON [dbo].[recharge_request]
FOR UPDATE
    AS
        DECLARE @uRefId varchar(20),@operator varchar(20),@rMobile varchar(20),@memberId varchar(20),@etopId varchar(20),@oReference varchar(20);
        DECLARE @status int,@amount int, @tId int;
        DECLARE @nAmount decimal(12,2),@cPercent decimal(12,2);
        DECLARE @isSMS bit;

        SELECT @uRefId=i.user_reference_id FROM inserted i; 
        SELECT @operator=i.operator FROM inserted i;
        SELECT @status=i.status FROM inserted i; 
        SELECT @amount=i.amount FROM inserted i;
        SELECT @memberId=i.uid FROM inserted i;
        SELECT @etopId=i.etop_id FROM inserted i;
        SELECT @isSMS=i.is_sms FROM inserted i;
        SELECT @rMobile=i.mobile_no FROM inserted i;
        SELECT @oReference=i.operator_reference_id FROM inserted i;

        IF UPDATE (status)
            BEGIN
                IF @status=7
                    UPDATE member_transaction SET is_succeed=0 WHERE reference_id=@uRefId;
                ELSE IF @status=1
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @cPercent=p_amount FROM extra_charges WHERE operator=@operator AND c_status=1;

                        IF @cPercent>0
                            BEGIN
                                SET @nAmount=(@amount*@cPercent)/100;

                                SELECT @tId=id FROM member_transaction WHERE reference_id=@uRefId AND remarks=@operator AND member_id=@memberId AND t_type='D' AND debit=@nAmount
                                IF @tId IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@tId) > 0
                                    SET @tId=0;
                                ELSE
                                    BEGIN
                                        INSERT INTO member_transaction(member_id,etop_id,t_type,debit,credit,particular,remarks,reference_id)
                                            VALUES(@memberId,@etopId,'D',@nAmount,0.00,'eDeduct : '+@operator+' '+@uRefId+', from : '+@etopId,@operator,@uRefId);
                                    END
                            END

                        UPDATE member_transaction SET is_succeed=1 WHERE reference_id=@uRefId;
                    END
                ELSE
                    UPDATE member_transaction SET is_succeed=1 WHERE reference_id=@uRefId;

                IF @isSMS=1
                    BEGIN

                        DECLARE @Mobile varchar(20);
                        DECLARE @rStatus varchar(20);
                        DECLARE @sms varchar(200);
                        DECLARE @balance decimal(12,2);
                        DECLARE @mName varchar(50);
                        IF @status=7
                            SET @rStatus='FAIL';
                        ELSE IF @status=1
                            SET @rStatus='SUCCESS';
                        IF @rStatus IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@rStatus) > 0
                            BEGIN

                                SELECT @Mobile=mobile,@mName=m_name FROM member_details WHERE id=@memberId;
                                SELECT @balance=SUM(debit)-SUM(credit) FROM member_transaction WHERE member_id=@memberId AND isnull(reference_id,0) NOT IN(SELECT user_reference_id FROM recharge_request WHERE status=7);
                                SET @sms ='RECHARGE ' + @rStatus + ' AND CONFIRM. Number: ' + @rMobile + ' Amt: ' + CONVERT(char(6), @amount) + ' TR-ID = '+ @oReference +' . Balance is ' + CONVERT(char(10), @balance);
                                EXEC spSendSmsSQL @mobile, @sms;

                                INSERT INTO member_transaction(member_id,etop_id,t_type,debit,particular,remarks)
                                    VALUES(@memberId,@etopId,'D',0.15,'SMS Charge for recharge by SMS','SMS Charges');

                                INSERT INTO hidden_charges(m_id,etop_id,m_name,amount,particular)
                                    VALUES(@memberId,@etopId,@mName,0.15,'SMS Charge for recharge by SMS');

                            END
                    END

            END
```

Please help me where I'm wrong.

Comment: This isn't something that a trigger should be doing anyway. Please show the code in the trigger that calls the proc.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your response....! I have edited my question  as you ask..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is my stupidity but I have solved by checking @oReference. oReference value is null and when I'm concatenate @sms is being NULL and it raise error.

```
  IF @oReference IS NULL
        SET @oReference='';
    SET @sms ='RECHARGE ' + @rStatus + ' AND CONFIRM. Number: ' + @rMobile + ' Amt: ' + CONVERT(char(6), @amount) + ' TR-ID = '+ @oReference +' . Balance is ' + CONVERT(char(10), @balance);
    EXEC spSendSmsSQL @mobile, @sms;
```